# Safari Ipad Video is transparent but present

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a problem on safari iOS ipad.

I have a video that start on a click on a button, and appear on top of everything autoplay, an disapear.

The video is inside an iframe (which has position absolute and a big z-index).

It works everywhere just perfectly, but when I'm on Safari iPad, the video play (you ear the sound) but do not appear. If i click on the part where the video should be, the "opacity" of when you select a dom element, show that the video is here, but it's like transparent. The only thing that appear is the close button which is a div in the same div of the video and it's the only other thing other than the video in the iframe.

The strange thing is, if I click or touchover the button, the video appear instantly.

I want to know if some of you got an idea to how fix it. Like a trick or a dirty thing to do just to prevent this. Like a way to make some sort of refresh of the browser to make everything appear correctly.

Thx, hope is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

dirty thing to prevent: use firefox/chrome ;)

Sorry I'm not sure I understand entirely what the problem is. Is this a video player you've made yourself?

Try this:

```
<video loop autoplay controls="true" width='100%' height='100%' src='/vidName' type='video/vidType'></video>
```

Comment: Have you got any extensions installed?

Comment: No i got nothing installed and i don't use a player.

I just make a <video> <video> and in js i do .play() .

In every browser the video start well and play.
Sadly, on this shitty Safari iOS the video start (you ear sound and saw the close button (the only custom thing)) but the video itself don't appear, it stay i think transparent. If i just "touch&drag" the button close, the video appear.

I think it's a safari bug... but i must find a way to fix this shitty :3

Comment: See edit. You might need to install some extensions to make safari treat html as IE/Chrome/Firefox do though...